# UIWebView shows blank unless reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I wrote a very simple app which includes a UIWebView.  [The gist can be found here](https://gist.github.com/zebralight/85950fe6cd380103647b).  Upon loading, all I see is a blank white scene.  In order to troubleshoot, I had added a button that refreshes the site.  The site loads upon pushing that button, so I'm left with the question as to why the site doesn't seem to load once the app loads.  I've coded it using XCode 6.1.1 for use with the iOS 8.1 SDK.  I've also confirmed that I hooked up the outlet to the UIWebView as can be sort of seen in the header file in the gist.  Are there any other troubleshooting steps or is there something glaringly obvious in my few lines of code that can be fixed immediately?  Thank you!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myWebView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)refreshButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [myWebView reload];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

This will only load local html file. Read the file & give the file contents to webview.
Instead, try to use:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```